# How to EmptyCase at the type level

Tags: haskell

Using `EmptyCase`, it is possible to implement the following function:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase, EmptyDataDecls #-}

data Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd v = case v of
```

With `DataKinds`, data types can be promoted to the kind level (their constructors are promoted to type constructors). This works for uninhabited data types like `Void` as well.

The question here is whether there is a way to write the equivalent of `absurd` for an uninhabited kind:

```hs
tabsurd :: Proxy (_ :: Void) -> a
tabsurd = _
```

This would effectively be a form of "`EmptyCase` at the type level". Within reason, feel free to substitute `Proxy` with some other suitable type (e.g. `TypeRep`).

NB: I understand that I can just resort to `error` or similar unsafe techniques here, but I want to see if there's a way to do this that would *not* work if the type wasn't uninhabited. So for whatever technique we come up with, it should not be possible to use the same technique to inhabit the following function:

```
data Unit = Unit

notsoabsurd :: Proxy (_ :: Unit) -> a
notsoabsurd = _
```

Comment: What would be the desired effect of such function? I mean, once you have it, how are you going to use it?

Comment: Something like `type family K :: MyKind` can be used to inhabit any kind, even if later on we do not provide equations for that. IIRC, there are no inhabited kinds in the GHC type systems because of this.

Comment: @chi yes, and `foo :: a; foo = undefined` can be used to inhabit any type, so there are no "uninhabited" types, and the question doesn't make sense. pro forma, let's forget about all that for the moment.

Comment: Correct, but note that using the type family above is possible even without using infinite recursion or enabling `UndecidableInstances`. Type checking will always halt in finite time, yet we have an inhabitant. So it's a bit more subtle than the trivial "bottom" value we find in each type.

Answer (score 4):

The type-level equivalent of pattern-matching is type classes (well, also type families, but they don't apply here, since you want a term-level result).

So you could conceivably make `tabsurd` a member of a class that has an associated type of kind `Void`:

```
class TAbsurd a where
  type TAbsurdVoid a :: Void
  tabsurd :: a
```

Here, `tabsurd` will have type signature `tabsurd :: TAbsurd a => a`, but if you insist on a `Proxy`, you can obviously easily convert one to the other:

```
pabsurd :: TAbsurd a => Proxy a -> a
pabsurd _ = tabsurd
```

So calling such function or using it in any other way would presumably be impossible, because you can't implement class `TAbsurd a` for any `a`, because you can't provide the type `TAbsurdVoid a`.

---

According to your requirement, the same approach does work fine for `Unit`:

```
data Unit = Unit

class V a where
  type VU a :: Unit
  uabsurd :: a

instance V Int where
  type VU Int = 'Unit
  uabsurd = 42
```

---

Keep in mind however that in Haskell, any kind (including `Void`) is potentially inhabited by a non-terminating type family. For example, this works:

```
type family F a :: x

instance TAbsurd Int where
  type TAbsurdVoid Int = F String
  tabsurd = 42
```

However, this limitation is akin to any *type* (including `Void`) being inhabited by the value `undefined` at term level, so that you can actually call `absurd` like this:

```
x = absurd undefined
```

The difference with type level is that you *can* actually call function `tabsurd` (given the instance above) and it will return `42`:

```
print (tabsurd :: Int)
```

This can be fixed by having `tabsurd` return not `a`, but a `Proxy (TAbsurdVoid a)`:

```
class TAbsurd a where
  type TAbsurdVoid a :: Void
  tabsurd :: Proxy (TAbsurdVoid a)
```

Comment: Hm,,, is this really what the OP was asking about, though? It seems `Void` is more just an implementation detail of how you make it impossible to declare a (proper) instance of `TAbsurd`, but it doesn't actually turn up in the signature of `pabsurd` in any way. IOW, basically what you're describing here is [`nope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Constraint-Trivial.html#v:nope), which doesn't use `Void` (but does use levity polymorphism to preclude the ⊥ backdoor).

Comment: Well, I did ask a clarifying question, but in the absence of a clarification I have to interpret the question one way or another.